# Passing data from ngContent in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I want to create childComponent which generate datagrid. So, I create grid.component.html and grid.component.ts. My aim is, my team mate never touch grid.ts and grid.html. Because my grid structure will be similar in for all page in my app. So, they only add like myComponent.html and myComponent.ts. They will write button's html and button's click event to myComponent. I can create grid. But my problem is, I can't access rowData in showDetail method. ("rowData" is implicit of primeNg directive. I wasn't setting anywhere. I only gave p-table value.)

### myComponent.html

```
<app-grid>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData="rawData">
        <button label="Reject" (click)="reject(rowData)"></button>
        <button label="Detail" (click)="showDetail(rowData)"></button>
  </ng-template>
</app-grid>
```

### myComponent.ts

```
reject(data){
  console.log("Reject data ", data);
}

showDetail(data){
   console.log("showDetail data ", data);
}
```

### grid.component.ts

```
rawData = {}

@ContentChild(TemplateRef)
templateRef : TemplateRef<any>;
```

### grid.component.html

```
<p-table [value]="globalVariables.myData">
   <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>  // This rowData come from PrimeNg "implicit" value
     <tr>
       <td *ngFor="let col of globalVariables.columns">
          {{ rowData[col.field] }}
       </td>
       <td>
         <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="templateRef; context : {rawData : rawData}"></ng-template>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is dynamic html template which can act as the part parent component `app-grid`. So you should use `<ng-template>` instead of `<ng-content>`.

you `app-grid` will be as

## grid.component.html

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ng-template 
     *ngTemplateOutlet="templateRef; context : {rawData : rawData, reject : reject, showDetail : showDetail}"
     >
     </ng-template>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## grid.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, TemplateRef, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid',
  templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid.component.css']
})
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  rawData = { content : " some content here"}

  @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
  templateRef : TemplateRef<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  reject(data){
    console.log("Reject data ", data);
  }

  showDetail(data){
     console.log("showDetail data ", data);
  }

}
```

## Use component grid

```
<app-grid>
  <ng-template let-rowData="rawData" let-reject="reject" let-showDetail="showDetail">
    <button label="Reject" (click)="reject(rowData)">Reject</button>
    <button label="Detail" (click)="showDetail(rowData)">Show Details</button>
  </ng-template>
</app-grid>
```

You can see the working copy here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g15twn

Comment: Thanks a lot @SunilSingh. You save my a lot of my time. It worked. But i don't know anything how it work. I think I need to find out what the "TemplateRef" and "ContentChild" is. What is the difference ContentChild from "input" and "output"?

Comment: There are many article which has pretty good explanation. 
 *ViewChild vs ContentChild* - https://medium.com/@tkssharma/understanding-viewchildren-viewchild-contentchildren-and-contentchild-b16c9e0358e
*TemplateRef* - https://blog.mgechev.com/2017/10/01/angular-template-ref-dynamic-scoping-custom-templates/

Comment: My last question is, in your example "showDetail" function in grid.component.ts. But in my project, "showDetail" method in myComponent.ts. So, when console.log, in console wrote undefined. How can access from myComponent.ts? @SunilSingh

Comment: In that case you should propagate the event from `app-grid` component to `my-component` and this can be done through `@Output`. I have updated the code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g15twn. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: I've made a lot of progress thanks to you. But I 'm sorry for not explaining exactly what I wanted in my previous comment and I took your a lot of time. I remove my question and I recreate the texts and codes. 
Because I can't explain exactly in the comment. I don't want passing methods. I want only rowData. And I don't want adding methods to grd.component.ts. Because thousand of button will be in project. Please check the question again ? @SunilSingh

Comment: I see your point. You want the grid component to handle the multiple button events. In other words you can have one or more button and you don't want to write the method for each button separately. If thats the case please open the new discussion and share the link here. Will be happy to help you.

Comment: Yes. I will write grid.component.ts and grid.component.html completely. And anybody don't touch them. Every team-mate in my team will write their fooComponent.html and fooComponent.ts. But they will write button htmls and methods themselves in myComponent.html and  myComponent.ts like in my question.

Comment: What is my mistake in my new edited code in my question? @SunilSingh

Comment: The issue looks at `{rawData : rawData}`. Just print `{{ rawData | json}}`. If you have implicit object `rawData` then you can remove this variable from `grid.component.ts` file.

Comment: You are wonderfuI. Thanks for save my day. I changed  let-rowData="rawData"  to let-rowData="rowData" . And {rawData : rawData} to {rowData : rowData}. Json pipe gave me error. So i didn't use. But it worked perfectly without json pipe. Thanks a lot @SunilSingh

Comment: That's a nice answer, thanks. Is it possible to have multiple ng-template ? For example, doing this with a card and have two areas, content and actions. How would you identify which ng-template goes where ?

Comment: I tried putting two ng-template but both get the content from the first template in the parent

Comment: I managed to do it by passing the template reference as an input from the parent but I'm not sure it's the most elegant way.

Answer (score -3):

Use the **@Input** in the child component

```
<ng-content [rowData] = 'rowData' ></ng-content>
```

myComponent.ts

```
@Input rowData: any;
```

Comment: I think, I must use Output not input. Because, rowData is in child element. And I will pass child to parent. I can't achieve this. Because, rowData is not my variable. That is created by primeNg. @Selina